# Having a limit to the amount of data shown in Frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

Currently I'm using Strapi as my CMS and NextJs/React for my front end. I have a .map function to list out all of my data from my starpi client and it works fine, but I want to add an limit to how many cards I want to show.
This is what I'm trying to achieve, where if there are more than 2 cards, the 3rd card just shows a link that takes you to a page where the other excess data are:

[image]

Currently this is my code:

```
<div class="flexbox-container" style={{margin:"70px", marginTop:"0px"}}>
        {
          posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <div style={{ padding: "40px" }}>

          <div class="citizen-item" key={post.id}>
          {console.log(post)}          
            <div className="container6">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", minHeight:"180px" }}
                src={`http://localhost:1337${post.Thumbnail.url}`}
              />
              <div style={{textAlign:"center", color:"#E3AB50", padding:"10px", fontSize:"20px"}}>{post.Title}</div>
              <div style={{textAlign:"center", color:"#000", padding:"10px", fontSize:"15px"}}>Access to {post.Countries} countries</div>
              <div style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", paddingTop:"20px", paddingBottom:"10px"}}>
              <button class="findButton">FIND OUT MORE</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
        ))}
        </div>
{/* Find Out more Card */}
      <div style={{padding:"40px"}}>
        <div class="citizen-item" style={{height:"100%", minHeight:"348.8px"}}>   
            <div className="container6" style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}>
              
              <div style={{textAlign:"center", color:"#E3AB50", padding:"10px", fontSize:"20px"}}>CARIBBEAN CITIZENSHIP</div>
              <div style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", paddingTop:"20px", paddingBottom:"10px"}}>
              <button class="findButton">APPLY NOW</button>
              </div>
              <div style={{textAlign:"center", color:"#0E2043", padding:"10px",paddingTop:"30px", fontSize:"15px"}}>COMPARE PROGRAMS</div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you done some research on how to achieve it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are accessing your strapi API to collections.
What I mean by that is that there are two ways of achieving what you want.

1. Will be by building an endpoint that does whet you want by using strapi query.

For this option, you can check: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#queries

2. Will be by accessing your collections by using the strapi standard API.

On the second case, you have to include API parameters to your request.
You will be interested in one or two parameters `START` and `LIMIT`.
In the first case, `LIMIT` will allow you to call a number or items. i.e.

```
GET /posts?_limit=5
```

Will return 5 posts.

That convinced with `Start` will allow you to paginate your calls. i.e.

```
GET /posts?_start=10&_limit=5
```

This will return items from 10 to 15.

For more info about this, read:
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#api-parameters